# handle variable defined in componentDidMount() in render() function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am facing this issue with componentDidMount() and render() in react.

In my `componentDidMount()` I am making an ajax call to get data from server (express+mysql) and I am setting this data in my state variable `dashboardData`

```
componentDidMount() {
        const headers = { 'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('authToken') }
        axios.get('http://localhost:3001/getDashboardData', {headers})
          .then(res => {
            this.setState({
                dashboardData: res.data.data
            })
          })
    }
```

and in my `render()` I am doing something like this

```
const data = this.state.dashboardData
const chartData = data.map(function(record) {
    return {
        labels: [record.Received, record.Approved, record.Pending],
        datasets: [{
            data: [300, 50, 100],
            backgroundColor: ['#FF6384', '#36A2EB', '#FFCE56'],
            hoverBackgroundColor: ['#FF6384', '#36A2EB', '#FFCE56']
        }]
    }
})

const chart = <Doughnut data={chartData} width={100} height={100} />
```

But here I am getting `chartData not defined` error which is probably because during my first rendering chartData is not defined as there is not dashboardData state variable. How to handle this.

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            dashboardData:[]
        }
    }
```

Comment: could u please share the constructor

Comment: @jsDevia I have added the constructor.

Comment: use data={ chartData || [] },this will pass chartData if it's defined else an empty array

Comment: You have fixed it all yourself. I guess you just haven't updated the browser code as it catches it all. Your browser still has the old code. Just re-run your app in incognito mode or try clearing cache and then run your app again. It shouldn't throw any error as your code is all correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think Your `Doughnut`  component is highly dependent on data props so I would recommend you to hide `Doughnut`  component until you get response from `ajax`

```
return (
   const chart = {data.length>0 && (<Doughnut data={chartData} width={100} height={100} />)}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass an empty array to handle the initial rendering

```
const data = this.state.dashboardData || [];
if(data.length == 0){
  return <div>No data available</div>;
}
const chartData = data.map(function(record) {
    return {
        labels: [record.Received, record.Approved, record.Pending],
        datasets: [{
            data: [300, 50, 100],
            backgroundColor: ['#FF6384', '#36A2EB', '#FFCE56'],
            hoverBackgroundColor: ['#FF6384', '#36A2EB', '#FFCE56']
        }]
    }
})

const chart = <Doughnut data={chartData} width={100} height={100} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a conditional operator that will return either false or the result of data.map to chartData

`const chartData = data && data.map()`

Answer (score 0):

U can also add a loader while fetching your dashboard data. Once your data is fetched, based on that u can render your component.

```
componentDidMount() {
  axios.get('http://localhost:3001/getDashboardData', {headers})
  .then(res => {
      this.setState({
          dashboardData: res.data.data,
          loader: false   // set it as true in initial state
      })
   })
   .catch(err => {
       this.setState({
           loader: false
       })
   })
}
```

`const chart = this.state.loader ? <Loader /> : <Doughnut data={chartData} width={100} height={100} />`

And In your chart data you can handle empty array, and display proper msg.